# HTML select not working correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm coding a calculator that uses an HTML select box. However, the select values aren't posting properly with my PHP code. Can anyone offer possible insight? I have no idea what is wrong. You can try the calculator here: http://macrorevolution.com/calculators/1-rep-max/

When I press submit, the value is cleared and no result is given. On my other calculators such as this one: http://macrorevolution.com/calculators/total-daily-energy-expenditure/ , the inputted value stays after submitting.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$repsv = "";
$weightliftv = "";
$answer = "";
if(isset($_POST['weightliftv'])) {
    $repsv = $_POST['repsv'];
    $weightliftv = $_POST['weightliftv'];
    if ($repsv=='0');
    else if($repsv=='1v') $repsv=1;
    else if($repsv=='2v') $repsv=1.0285949393;
    else if($repsv=='3v') $repsv=1.0588733587;
    else if($repsv=='4v') $repsv=1.0909884355;
    else if($repsv=='5v') $repsv=1.1251125112;
    else if($repsv=='6v') $repsv=1.1614401858;
    else if($repsv=='7v') $repsv=1.2001920307;
    else if($repsv=='8v') $repsv=1.2416190713;
    else if($repsv=='9v') $repsv=1.2860082305;
    else if($repsv=='10v') {$repsv=1.3333333333; echo "10";}
    else echo "error";
    $answer = $weightliftv * $repsv;
}
?>
```

Here is the html code in the same file:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">


    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td>Weight Lifted:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='agev' value="<?php echo $agev; ?>"/>lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td>Reps Done</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <select name="repsv">
  <option name='repsv' selected='selected' value=''>Select</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='1v'>1 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='2v'>2 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='3v'>3 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='4v'>4 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='5v'>5 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='6v'>6 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='7v'>7 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='8v'>8 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='9v'>9 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='10v'>10 Reps</option>
         </select>
        </td>
        </tr>

    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' class="button highlight small" value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Your one rep max is </strong><input type='text' style="width: 50px; font-weight:bold;" value='<?php echo round($answer,0); ?>' /><strong>lbs</strong>  </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Here is the full code if necessary:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: 1repcalc
*/
?>



<?php get_header(); ?>



<?php $al_options = get_option('al_general_settings');?>



<!-- Title -->

<div class="box pt20">

    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="headertext">

        <?php the_title() ?>

        <?php $headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_headline", $single = false);?>

        <?php if(!empty($headline[0]) ):?>

            <span><?php echo $headline[0] ?></span>

        <?php endif?>

    </div>

    <div class="clearsmall"></div>



    <!-- Promo text -->

    <?php $promo = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_promo", $single = false);?>

    <?php if(!empty($promo[0]) ):?>

       <div class="calloutcontainer">

            <div class="container_12">

                <div class="grid_12">            

                    <?php echo do_shortcode($promo[0]);?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>    

    <?php endif?>

    <div class="container_12">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<?php
$repsv = "";
$weightliftv = "";
$answer = "";
if(isset($_POST['weightliftv'])) {
    $repsv = $_POST['repsv'];
    $weightliftv = $_POST['weightliftv'];
    if ($repsv=='0');
    else if($repsv=='1v') $repsv=1;
    else if($repsv=='2v') $repsv=1.0285949393;
    else if($repsv=='3v') $repsv=1.0588733587;
    else if($repsv=='4v') $repsv=1.0909884355;
    else if($repsv=='5v') $repsv=1.1251125112;
    else if($repsv=='6v') $repsv=1.1614401858;
    else if($repsv=='7v') $repsv=1.2001920307;
    else if($repsv=='8v') $repsv=1.2416190713;
    else if($repsv=='9v') $repsv=1.2860082305;
    else if($repsv=='10v') {$repsv=1.3333333333; echo "10";}
    else echo "error";
    $answer = $weightliftv * $repsv;
    echo $answer;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>One Rep Max Calculator</title>
<style>
  table {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  }
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
  padding:0em 1em 1em 0em;

}
p.ss {
    font-size:30px; 
    text-align:center
}
input {
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box pt20">
<p class="ss">MacroRevolution One Rep Max Calculator</p><br>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td colspan="4">

All weight training and resistance training programs are always based off of your 1 rep max. If you are uncertain of your 1 rep max you can use the 1 rep max calculator below to help get you pretty close to that number.
In many cases we find that the 1 rep max calculator is accurate within 5%. The closer you can get to completing 1 rep at maximum effort, the more accurate it will be!
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form method='post' action=''>
<table width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">


    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td>Weight Lifted:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='agev' value="<?php echo $agev; ?>"/>lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td>Reps Done</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <select name="repsv">
  <option name='repsv' selected='selected' value=''>Select</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='1v'>1 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='2v'>2 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='3v'>3 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='4v'>4 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='5v'>5 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='6v'>6 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='7v'>7 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='8v'>8 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='9v'>9 Reps</option>
  <option name='repsv' value='10v'>10 Reps</option>
         </select>
        </td>
        </tr>

    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' class="button highlight small" value='Calculate'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Your one rep max is </strong><input type='text' style="width: 50px; font-weight:bold;" value='<?php echo round($answer,0); ?>' /><strong>lbs</strong>  </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>


<table border='0' width='80%' style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <td colspan="4">

      <br>
If you want to calculate your formula....
 <br><br><br>
    </td>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: First you don't need to name the options, just the select

Comment: Second, I don't see a weightliftv input, where is that located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an input for weightliftv. If there is one then it might be the ; after the if ($repsv=='0'); remove it and it should work.

A few notes though. Don't need the isset. if($_POST['weightliftv']) { does the same thing. You don't need to name each option, just the select they belong to. Don't forget to filter your posts so they are more secure (filter_var()).

```
<?php echo $var; ?> can be shortened to <?=$var;?>
```

else if($repsv=='10v') {$repsv=1.3333333333; echo "10";} has curly braces when not needed. They don't hurt anything, but it makes your code more uniform and easier to read.

That many select options can be put into a loop.

```
for($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {
  <option name='repsv' value='1v'>1 Reps</option>
}

<?php
    $repsv = "";
    $weightliftv = "";
    $answer = "";
    if(isset($_POST['weightliftv'])) {
        $repsv = $_POST['repsv'];
        $weightliftv = $_POST['weightliftv'];
        if ($repsv=='0');
        else if($repsv=='1v') $repsv=1;
        else if($repsv=='2v') $repsv=1.0285949393;
        else if($repsv=='3v') $repsv=1.0588733587;
        else if($repsv=='4v') $repsv=1.0909884355;
        else if($repsv=='5v') $repsv=1.1251125112;
        else if($repsv=='6v') $repsv=1.1614401858;
        else if($repsv=='7v') $repsv=1.2001920307;
        else if($repsv=='8v') $repsv=1.2416190713;
        else if($repsv=='9v') $repsv=1.2860082305;
        else if($repsv=='10v') {$repsv=1.3333333333; echo "10";}
        else echo "error";
        $answer = $weightliftv * $repsv;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to change agev to weightliftv. Silly me. But thanks for giving me tips on cleaning up my code. I do not understand the for loop however

Comment: The for loop is just to put into your html form instead of writing each one out, u just choose how many you want displaced. Give it a try, it may help with future coding and be a tiny stepping stone to more advanced programming